# python image sequence file pattern regex

Tags: python, regex

A file in an image sequence typically looks something like this: image.001.png, where "001" is the frame number of this image. I am trying to construct a sequence pattern that will capture in groups: 1) everything before the frame number, 2) the frame number, 3) the extension.

I'm totally new to regex and I'm having trouble creating a pattern which will work in every possible case I can think of. So far here are the possible cases I know of, and what I would like to capture in parentheses below:

```
img123.png
(img) (123) (png)

img.123.png
(img.) (123) (png)

img_v01_1234.png
(img_v01_) (1234) (png)

img01_123.png
(img01_) (123) (png)

img.001.123.png
(img.001.) (123) (png)

img 001.12.png
(img 001.) (12) (png)
```

I only know of two stable assumptions I can make. 1) there will be a 3-4 character file extension (obviously preceded by a period). 2) the frame number is always just before the file extension. Beyond that it is a free for all, which is where I get tripped up. Sometimes there are other numbers in the file name, and sometimes they have periods (or other characters) before/after them. So in essence I need to be able to capture the LAST instance of a series of numbers greater than 0 (hope that makes sense).

I found that `(.{3,4})$` will match a file extension, while `([0-9]+)` will match any sequence of numbers. So the following gets me nearly there, I'm just missing everything before the sequence number as a group: `([0-9]+)\.(.{3,4})$`

Comment: I find regular expressions an unmaintainable mess. What about `pyparsing`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I'm finding I don't totally love them either. I can do this quite easily just using the default modules... I wanted to go regex because I thought that was the more acceptable way, but perhaps that is just a fixed idea?

Comment: Regex are fast and well known. They are a legit choice but I really don't like them. Too cryptic.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Yeah, makes sense. For now I'll code a method in straight python, but leave the question open in case someone figures this one out! I'm sure it will be helpful to others out there, I'm not the only one with this problem (I was surprised I couldn't already find an answer for this online, plenty of animation studios out there must have solved this before)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Well that was fast! wp78de just got it.

Comment: @wp78de Actually I was just thinking about that. Technically yes, however I've never seen a file like that and honestly I'm not too worried about it in my case. I did try it out for fun and found that I can add an "optional" char `?` after the first group to catch this case.

Comment: if so, Alex's solution may not give you what you want in the capture groups: https://ideone.com/bHdMdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern is pretty much fine. To get the part before, you can just match all characters with a lazy quantifier (`?`) to stop when it reaches the numbers. So the full pattern is:

```
^(.+?)([0-9]+)\.(.{3,4})$
```

This will work for all characters and in my opinion is much simpler than a negative lookbehind.

Tests:

```
import re

tests = '''\
img123.png
(img) (123) (png)

img.123.png
(img.) (123) (png)

img_v01_1234.png
(img_v01_) (1234) (png)

img01_123.png
(img01_) (123) (png)

img.001.123.png
(img.001.) (123) (png)

img 001.12.png
(img 001.) (12) (png)'''


for pair in tests.split('\n\n'):
    filename, output = pair.strip().splitlines()
    assert (list(re.match(r'^(.+?)([0-9]+)\.(.{3,4})$', filename).groups()) ==
            re.findall(r'\((.+?)\)', output))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following pattern:

```
^([\w. ]+)(?<!\d)(\d+)\.(\w+)$
```

This matches all your test cases as required:

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ISDbCq/2)

---

So, if file names without a prefix are possible then you should indeed apply the modified pattern:

```
^(.*)(?<!\d)(\d+)\.(\w+)$
```

[**Demo2**](https://regex101.com/r/ISDbCq/3)

Comment: Yep, that does it! I just tweaked the first group to include all characters because I found I had another file name with a "-" in it, which caused the original pattern to fail. Looks like what I originally misunderstood was the negative lookbehind...